# php grabber - submission script

Tags: php, form-submit

Im programming php grabber. I want to grab some text and then compare grabbed content with content stored in my db from last scan. Everything works fine. But i would like to scan url where is a "filter" form so it is posting some data and therefore i cant see exact url to scan. Is there some way , my script will submit that form with data i want so it will show content i want for my script and after that i can grab content?

its something like

```
$url = 'myurl'; 
$data=get_data($url);
$grabbed=strip_tags(get_match('some regex',$data);

function get_data($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
function get_match($regex,$content)
{
    preg_match($regex,$content,$matches);
    return $matches[1];
}
```

This works great but i need that form submison script on that url that will make my content accessible. Is that possible?

Thanks a lot,

Martin.

## update :

```
    <?php
//url
$url = "http://data.skga.sk/Tournaments.aspx";

//get the page content
$content = get_data($url);
echo $content;
  


//gets the match content
function get_match($regex,$content)
{
    preg_match($regex,$content,$matches);
    return $matches[1];
}

//gets the data from a URL
function get_data($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "ctl00%24RightContentPlaceholder%24dpTo=20.10.2012");
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
?>
```

That is my code now. But i still dont know how to solve it. When i execute http://data.skga.sk/Tournaments.aspx?ctl00%24RightContentPlaceholder%24dpTo=20.10.2012 in browser it's fine. But when i run this php i can see default page

Comment: http://ligafiriem.eu/grabber/grabber.php this is the result of my script

Answer (score 0):

You can handle post requests like this:

```
curl_setopt($curl_handler, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl_handler, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($curl_handler, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

... where $url is the url from `<form action="[url]" [...]` and $postdata is a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...'.

See also: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Example: You want to submit a form like:

```
<form action="http://example.com/login.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

This is what you would do:

```
<?php
$curl_handler = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl_handler, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_handler, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl_handler, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "name=admin&password=secret");
curl_setopt($curl_handler, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/login.php");

$data = curl_exec($curl_handler);
curl_close($curl_handler);
?>
```

Comment: hey thats the page i want to grab from. http://www.skga.sk/zoznam-turnajov/ there is calendar which is textbox but i want post data of Platnost do : which is `<input type="text" name="ctl00$RightContentPlaceholder$dpTo">` form action is Tournaments.aspx. I found whole url is http://data.skga.sk/Tournaments.aspx . This i set to curlopt_url. ctl00$RightContentPlaceholder$dpTo=20.19.2012 is my poststring. where am i doing mistake?

Comment: In this case, you need to post every required field. 'ctl00$RightContentPlaceholder$dpTo' is not enough. Make sure you are also posting the value of '__VIEWSTATE' which is some long string you need to crawl/extract before posting your request to the server. 'ctl00_RightContentPlaceholder_dpFrom' seems to be relevant as well to me.

Comment: ok. But what is 'every required field' cuz when i click filter there are 2 default values ctl00$RightContentPlaceholder$dpTo and ctl00$RightContentPlaceholder$dpFrom. But my question is. When i do post via curl its only posts values i sending or values that are actually written in input...

Comment: so this is not working :`<?php

 $remotehost_cgi = 'http://remotehost.com/index.aspx';
 $ret = post_data("ctl00%24RightContentPlaceholder%24dpFrom=20.09.2012&ctl00%24RightContentPlaceholder%24dpTo=20.10.2012", 'http://data.skga.sk/Tournaments.aspx');
 echo $ret;


function post_data($datatopost,$urltopost){
 $crl = curl_init ($urltopost);
 curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datatopost);
 curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $returndata = curl_exec ($crl);
 return $returndata;
}

?>`

Comment: ok now i can see _VIEWSTATE is changing after posting. But can i determine behaviour of VIEWSTATE in dependence of dpFrom and dpTo? oh i have a headache from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using curl you may want to use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1)` to switch to a POST request and `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields)` to carry whatever post data you need to include with the request. More on Curl options from the [curl_setopt documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).